# Toggling off and turning off Validators good practice in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular8

We have a Form in Angular below. A new requirement came out, that some people only want to only use some of the 10 fields below. So what our team is doing is: hiding fields, and toggling off the Validators in both the typescript form and html below.

The question is, is this good practice in Angular? My idea is have new formbuilder models which can be swapped in and out of components. Seems like turning off validators and html can leave unnecessary code, and further entagle code. What happens if we create new fields, be added with toggles. Right now, all our 10 fields have toggles, and it seems to be getting messy .

Just curious if this is standard practice in Angular Official document recommendation?

If it doesn't matter, is there a better way to manage rather than having 10 boolean variables for 10 form controls?

```
this.customerForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  'customerName': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'productBought': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]],
  'streetNumber': [null, [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(64)]],
  'streetName': [null, [Validators.maxLength(8)]],
  'city': [null, [Validators.maxLength(32)]],
  'state': [null, [Validators.maxLength(16)]],
  'postalCode': [null, [Validators.maxLength(16)]],
  'postalCodeExtension': [null, [Validators.maxLength(50)]]
 }, 
}


'city': [null, this.cityShow === true ? [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(50)] : []],


<div class="parent" *ngIf="cityShow">
    City:
     <input formControlName = "city" class = "cityclass"> 
     </input>
</div>
```

Comment: "Good practice" questions are almost always [opinion based and not suitable for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). One persons "nasty hack" is another's "clever solution"

Comment: well, I am asking about what Angular Official document recommendation states, and what google states,  more about what standards and methodologies are with the offical vendor

Comment: There is no official documentation on this to my knowledge. If it works, it works, if it't the right thing to do <shrug> can you justify it when someone asks why you did it?

Comment: This could **possibly** be a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that create differents forms is more suitable. you can has in an array the fields necesary and use addControl

e.g.

```
controls=['customerName','streetNumber','postalCode' ]
this.customerForm = new FormGroup({})
if (controls.indexOf('customerName')>=0)
   this.customerForm.addControl('customerName',new FormControl(null,Validators.maxLength(50))
if (controls.indexOf('productBought')>=0)
   this.customerForm.addControl('productBought',new FormControl(null,Validators.maxLength(50))
if (controls.indexOf('streetName')>=0)
   this.customerForm.addControl('streetName',new FormControl(null,Validators.maxLength(8))
...

}

//In .html
<div *ngIf="controls.indexOf('customerName')>
   Customer :
   <input formControlName="customerName">
   ...
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, you said you want creating different formbuilders is more suitable, as I stated in question,  or do you also recommend your method below? I will research appreciate it

Comment: is controls an @Input parameter?

Comment: just started reading interesting strategies also,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38007236/how-to-dynamically-add-and-remove-form-fields-in-angular-2

Comment: and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49266469/angular-reactive-forms-adding-and-removing-fields,   however you are really adding to it, kind of seeing value in theanswer

Comment: seems like we can simplify answer into a while loop? will research this, its giving me some ideas,

Comment: really a loop implia has a complex array object, at least, the label and the placeholder, perhapfs a error message too (if you want to use in severals idioms, the problem grows), some fields can be checkbox or select... puff. Of course is possible, but I don't think it was necesary. The array controls, can be a variable, get it form a json file or from a dbs... If you has the form in a "child" component, you can use an array of course, it's only an example